# Obtain all jira issues based on its project name and labels

Tags: python, conditional-statements, jira, python-jira

Well first off, I used `issues = jira.get_project_issuekey_all("project_name")` to obtain all the issues in my project but I am only getting 50 results back. How would I go about getting all of the results?

Secondly, once this is figured out, I am wondering how I would be able to check if an issue would have a certain label. As far as I come is figuring out `jira.issue_field_value('issue key', 'labels')`.

I want to combine these two conditions so that it will return all the issues under a certain project with a specific label. Any thoughts?

Comment: I decided to include JQL and I was able to figure out the second part of my question which would be returning issues under a particular project and certain label. `JQL = 'project = TEST AND labels = "TEST"'
data = jira.jql(JQL)`

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find `get_project_issuekey_all`? I can't find any mention of it in the api reference.

Anyhoo...

You can feed a JQL query to `search_issues` to find the issues that match the project and label that you're interested in.

For example, let's say that you want to find all of the issues in project "MYISSUES" with the label "stuff".

Use the standard Jira web interface search GUI to test your jql query, then assign it as a string that you pass to `search_issues`:

```
my_jql_query = 'project = MYISSUES AND labels = stuff'
issues = jira.search_issues(my_jql_query, maxResults=1000)
```

Note that you will be limited to a response of 50 results unless you specify `maxResults`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I was using Atlassian's Jira module. You can find the function located here: https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/jira.html#manage-issues